# Trying to install xubuntu in MacBook air

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, xfce, battery, macbook

I have a MacBook air without a battery that was practically unusable because without a battery it is very slow. So I decided to install xubuntu. So I made a bootable USB and tried to install, everything was going well but every time I try to install, more or less at 3/4 of the installation the computer freezes and this appears:

```
irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Handlers:
usb_hcd_irq
usb_hcd_irq
i965_irq_handler [i915]
Disabling IRQ #16
i2c i2c-2: sendbytes: NAK bailout
```

I have tried to install instead Ubuntu so that after that I could install xfce but the same situation happened.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me, sorry if my english is not perfect, it is not my mother language.

Comment: MacOS could not function without a working battery?  That leads me to believe that the *hardware* cannot function without a working battery: Apple is very in tune with their OS/Hardware relationship because they have full control over the ecosystem. I would guess that if the hardware is so damaged that it can't run the OS that was designed for it, that perhaps nothing will run on it.

Comment: At first I thought that, but I found in the os x system a process in the  monitor of activity called rpcsvchost that only starts if you do not have a battery, if you finish that process the performance of the lap improves a lot. But after a time it starts again, so that is why I decided to try to install xubuntu in it. If I select the try option despite of being an USB it runs pretty well. P. D. Thanks for editing the lines of console, I tried to put them in order but its the first time that I use this forum (that I find great) and for some reason they went to disorder

Answer (score 0):

I did it, for people with a similar problem this is what I did.
I was trying with the newer version of xubuntu 20.04. I have just tried with xubuntu 12.04 and with this version I didn't had a problem, it even connected to Internet without having to do any additional steps, just like a normal lap